# Naming data frame columns according to a piece of a string in another separate data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe, naming

In one data frame I have a string which looks like this:

```
   *Census Tract 101.02, Fairfield County, Connecticut!!Families!!Estimate*
   *Census Tract 104.03, Windsor County, Connecticut!!Families!!Estimate*
```

I would like to create a new data frame with column named after the tract. That means the number (ie. 101.2) alone would constitute the title for each columns.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example and explain what you want to get to.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] including a sample dataset. As of now, I do not understand what your asking for. Thank you.